# Bounded and unbounded homeomorphic metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm struggling to come up with an example of homeomorphic metric spaces such that one is bounded and one is not

Comment: What about $]0;1[$ and $]-\infty;0[$ with $d(x,y) = |x-y|$?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\tan : (-\pi,\pi) \to \mathbb R
$$
That is a homeomorphism from $(-\pi,\pi)$ to $\mathbb R$.

So is this: $x \mapsto \dfrac x {\pi^2-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology.  Let $d_1(x,x) =0$ and otherwise $1$.  Let $d_2 (x,y)=|x-y|$.  Both metrics produce the discrete topology, and only one of them is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $\mathbb{R}$ and $]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$ as metrics spaces for the usual metric, then you can check that $\arctan:\mathbb{R}\to]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$ is an homeomorphism. For this metric, you have that $\mathbb{R}$ is not bounded whereas $]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[\subset B(0,2)$.